# Analyticity of complex derivative and conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a complex function $\phi(z)$ that is analytic, can I say that the following are analytic?

1) $\phi '(z)$

2) $\overline{\phi '(z)}$

3) $z\overline{\phi '(z)}$

My end goal is to compute the following contour integral:

$$
\oint_C \phi(z)-z\overline{\phi '(z)}+\overline{\phi '(z)} dz
$$

which has a singularity along the boundary where I would like to use the residue theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) is indeed Analytic.

2) is analytic if and only if $\phi'(z)$ is a constant.

This follows from the fact that if $\overline{\phi'(z)}$ is Analytic on some open set $U$, then by 1) so are $\phi'(z)+\overline{\phi'(z)}$ and $\frac{\phi'(z)-\overline{\phi'(z)}}{2i}$. But these are real valued functions, and it can be proven that analityc + real valued= constant.

3) If $z\overline{\phi '(z)}$ is analytic on any open set $U$ then on $U \backslash \{ 0\}$ 
$$z\overline{\phi '(z)} =\frac{z\overline{\phi '(z)}}{z}$$
is also Analytic. It follows from (2) that $\phi'(z)$ must be constant on $U \backslash \{ 0\}$, and since $\phi$ is Analytic on $U$, it follows that $\phi'(z)$ must be constant on $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Only 1) is necessarily analytic. To see that 2) need not be analytic, take $\phi(z) = z^2$; for 3), take $\phi(z) = z$ (Assuming 3) is $\overline{z\phi'(z)}$; if you meant $z\cdot \overline{\phi'(z)}$, then take $\phi(z) = z^2$.)